# PowerShell from .NET calling MsmqQueueManager

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script which I am trying to call from .NET (vb.net) using the PowerShell.Create method to create the pipeline.  The script just calls Set-MsmqQueueManager.  The code works fine on my development machine, however, on the Windows Server 2012 R2 server I deploy it to Powershell returns the following error in the error streams:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Msmq.Runtime.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A) File name: 'Microsoft.Msmq.Runtime.Interop.dll' at Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.SetMSMQQueueManagerCommand.BeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()

I have tried various Import-Module statements, I have tried including the System.Messaging.dll and even using it to Add-Type but nothing has worked so far.  I can run other scripts in this manner without any issues.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: First guess... shot in the dark... is your test system and Server different architectures? Perhaps the dll is only available in x86  PowerShell and you are running x64?

Comment: Thanks... I can manually run the script with either 32 or 64bit  PowerShell on the server without issues.  My application is being compiled with AnyCPU.  So I don't think that would be it.  But to be thorough I tried compiling the application in 64bit mode - same error.

Comment: Where is that dll located (full path) on the 2012 server? You either have to use absolute paths or the path is part of the PATH environment variable. Also system32 means different things in x86 and x64 environments. I'm not sure otherwise.

Comment: Well, when I run the script (which just contains that one command) through Powershell, it doesn't require any special dll or module - it just works.  But when I run it from the .NET application it throws that error.  I did find the dll in question in the SXS folder and tried to put it in the application folder, same error.

Comment: Forgive me as I do not want to lead you astray but I bet neither of those locations are part of the Path environment variable on that system

Comment: Thanks Matt, it can find the dll, it just can't load it.  I did a WinDbg session to confirm.  It throws 0x8007045A ERROR _DLL_INIT_FAILED when trying to load the dll.  But I can't find anywhere WHY it is failing to load.  Very frustrating!

Comment: Have you tried to use [dependancy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the dll in case it is just a dependency?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion, and I used the profile mode and proved that the dll was found and hooked, but it doesn't say why it can't be loaded: `Loaded "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\modules\msmq\MICROSOFT.MSMQ.RUNTIME.INTEROP.DLL" at address 0x00007FFAF77F0000.  Successfully hooked module.`  but then a few lines down it says `LoadLibraryExW("C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\MSMQ\Microsoft.Msmq.Runtime.Interop.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed (1114).`